# Сборка и разборка предложения на отдельные компоненты

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, list, текст

Есть некий текст, я его разбил на ArrayList абзацев, предложений и слов. Код может разобрать/собрать этот текст из/в файл(-а), просто в каждой сущности вызывать вложенный лист(наследника). 
Нужно ещё сделать так, что бы предложение разбивалось на знаки препинания, слова, числа, символы и т.д. Слышал, что через регулярки можно задать паттерн чисел и символов. Но как на практике это сделать не знаю, точно так же как и придумать способ разборки и сборки.
Была идея создания листа с элементами после слова, а-ля 
"Привет, дорогой Мир!"
List - {",", "", "!"}

Но она мне не особо нравится, и это только знаки препинания, а нужно ещё вычислять отдельные символы. Табуляции и множественные пробелы можно заменить одним пробелом.
Может кто идею подкинуть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это легко делается через регулярное выражение:

```
String sentences = "Привет, дорогой Мир!";
String regex = "[,!]";
String[] parts = sentences.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

В квадратных скобках указываете все символы, по которым нужно разбивать.

Усли вы хотите разбить по символам, при этом сохранив их, то тогда регулярное выражение меняется:

```
String sentences = "Привет, дорогой Мир!";
String regex = "(?<=,)|(?=,)|(?<=!)|(?=!)";
String[] parts = sentences.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Comment: Такие строки у меня в коде есть. Только всё равно это мне не очень помогло. Сформулирую ещё раз. Мне бы получить отдельный List со знаками препинания из предложения с возможностью сборки предложения с ними обратно. Также и слова, буквы и цифры

Comment: В ответе дописал вариант, который вы прсили.

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov, `(?<=[!,])|(?=[!,])` вполне рабочий вариант.